# How to compare all elements between two arrays?

Tags: java, math, graph

I'm attempting to write a program which can identify all nodes in a graph that don't share any common neighbors, and in which all vertices are contained within the various subsystems in the graph. Assume all nodes are numerically labeled for simplicity.

For example, in a graph of a cube, the furthest corners share no common nodes and are part of subsystems that together contain all vertices.

I'm looking to write a program that compares each potential subsystem against all other potential subsystems, regardless of the graph, number of nodes or sides, and finds groups of subsystems whose central nodes don't share common neighbors. For simplicity's sake, assume the graphs aren't usually symmetrical, unlike the cube example, as this introduces functionally equivalent systems. However, the number of nodes in a subsystem, or elements in an array, can vary.

The goal for the program is to find a set of central nodes whose neighbors are each unique to the subsystem, that is no neighbor appears in another subsystem. This would also mean that the total number of nodes in all subsystems, central nodes and neighbors together, would equal the total number of vertices in the graph.

My original plan was to use a 2d array, where rows act as stand-ins for the subsystems. It would compare individual elements in an array against all other elements in all other arrays. If two arrays contain no similar elements, then index the compared array and its central node is recorded, otherwise it is discarded for this iteration. After the program has finished iterating through the 2d array against the first row, it adds up the number of elements from all recorded rows to see if all nodes in the graph are represented. So if a graph contains x nodes, and the number of elements in the recorded rows is less than x, then the program iterates down one row to the next subsystem and compares all values in the row against all other values like before.

Eventually, this system should print out which nodes can make up a group of subsystems that encompass all vertices and whose central nodes share no common neighbors.

My limited exposure to CS makes a task like this daunting, as it's just my way of solving puzzles presented by my professor. I'd find the systems by hand through guess-and-check methods, but with a 60+ node array...

Thanks for any help, and simply pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are Java libraries (like JGraphT) with graph-algorithms that could be helpful

Comment: Just to verify: By subsystem you mean a central node together with its immediate neighbors, right? And you want to partition the graph into disjoint subsystems.

Comment: Yes, Nico. And the subsystems would need to cover all nodes within the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good solution (and maybe there exists none; it sounds very close to vertex cover). So you may need to resort backtracking. The idea is the following:

Keep a list of uncovered vertices and a list of potential central node candidates. Both lists initially contain all vertices. Then start placing a random central node from the candidate list. This will erase the node and its one-ring from the uncovered list and the node plus its one-ring and two-ring from the candidate list. Do this until the uncovered list is empty or you run out of candidates. If you make a mistake, revert the last step (and possibly more).

In pseudo-code, this looks as follows:

```
findSolution(uncoveredVertices : list, centralNodeCandidates : list, centralNodes : list)
    if uncoveredVertices is empty
        return centralNodes //we have found a valid partitioning
    if centralNodeCandidates is empty
        return [failure] //we cannot place more central nodes
    for every n in centralNodeCandidates
        newUncoveredVertices <- uncoveredVertices \ { n } \ one-ring of n
        newCentralNodeCandidates <- centralNodeCandidates \ { n } \ one-ring of n \ two-ring of n
        newCentralNodes = centralNodes u { n }
        subProblemSolution = findSolution(newUncoveredVertices, newCentralNodeCandidates, newCentralNodes)
        if subProblemSolution is not [failure]
            return subProblemSolution
    next
    return [failure] //none of the possible routes to go yielded a valid solution
```

Here, `\` is the set minus operator and `u` is set union.

There are several possible optimizations:

- If you know the maximum number of nodes, you can represent the lists as bitmaps (for a maximum of 64 nodes, this even fits into a 64 bit integer).
- You may end up checking the same state multiple times. To avoid this, you may want to cache the states that resulted in failures. This is in the spirit of dynamic programming.